# Loss of Image quality when set as lock screen or home screen wallpaper

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens, wallpaper

This is my original wallpaper:

[image: wallpaper]

After setting it as Lock Screen wallpaper, its quality got reduced and this is how it looks:

[image: wallpaper]

Even when set as homescreen, the image quality is reduced.

[image: wallpaper]

How to improve the quality of the lock screen/home screen wallpaper?

Comment: Nice pic -- and you are right, the original looks far better.

Comment: That simply appears to be the "effect" of the lockscreen (dimming and blurring the background?). Have you tried a lock screen app replacement such as WidgetLocker?

Comment: @BryanDenny no its not the effect. Check the edit for the homescreen wallpaper. Its quality also is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The original image size was huge (about 2600 pixels wide). So I used Photoshop and transformed this image to 960 x 480. Now the image looks the same way when set as lock screen or home screen wallpaper like below:

[image: wallpaper]